# AppSync Pebble: I get wrong values

Tags: android, c, callback, tuples, pebble-sdk

I am programming a Pebble Watchface and a Android App for this watchface. I haven't programmed with C before, so this is a bit tricky for me. The Problem is, that I always get 0 as key in the callback.

On the Pebble Side it looks like this:

```
static AppSync sync;
static uint8_t sync_buffer[32];
```

...

```
Tuplet initial_values[] = {
    TupletInteger(WEATHER_KEY, (uint8_t) 0),
    TupletInteger(TEMP_KEY, (uint8_t) 20),
    TupletInteger(PROB_KEY, (uint8_t) 50),
    TupletInteger(BATTERY_KEY, (uint8_t) 100),
    TupletInteger(RING_MODE_KEY, (uint8_t) 0),
    TupletCString(TITLE_KEY, "TITLE"),
    TupletCString(ARTIST_KEY, "ARTIST")
};
app_sync_init(&sync, sync_buffer, sizeof(sync_buffer), initial_values, ARRAY_LENGTH(initial_values),
    sync_tuple_changed_callback, sync_error_callback, NULL);
```

And the Callback:

```
void sync_tuple_changed_callback(const uint32_t key, const Tuple* new_tuple, const Tuple* old_tuple, void* context) {

static char temp_buf[] = "aaaaaaaa";
snprintf(temp_buf, sizeof(temp_buf), "%d,%d", (int)key, new_tuple->value->uint8);
text_layer_set_text(title_layer, temp_buf);
switch (key) {
    case WEATHER_KEY:
        set_weather_state(new_tuple->value->uint8);
        break;
    case TEMP_KEY:
        set_temp(new_tuple->value->uint8);
        break;
    case PROB_KEY:
        set_prob(new_tuple->value->uint8);
        break;
    case BATTERY_KEY:
        vibes_short_pulse();
        set_phone_percentage(new_tuple->value->uint8);
        break;
    case RING_MODE_KEY:
        set_ring_state(new_tuple->value->uint8);
        break;
    case TITLE_KEY:
        text_layer_set_text(title_layer, new_tuple->value->cstring);    
        break;
    case ARTIST_KEY:
        text_layer_set_text(artist_layer, new_tuple->value->cstring);   
        break;


}
```

}

On the Android side:

```
public void sendBatteryInformation(byte state) {
PebbleDictionary data = new PebbleDictionary();
data.addUint8(3, (byte)30);
PebbleKit.sendDataToPebble(getApplicationContext(), PEBBLE_APP_UUID,
    data);
}
```

When I call the Android function sendBatteryInformation, the callback on the watch gets triggered. Because none of the cases were executed, I printed the key and the value to the textlayer "title_layer". It always prints "0,20" there, although I send "3" as a key.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The value `TupletInteger(WEATHER_KEY, (uint8_t) 0),` is initialized to 0.  Is there any reason to think that value changed before the callback is called?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you ask if the value of that Tuplet is changed? I searched through my code and I don't change the initial_values[] anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
I had to increase the buffers.
Also: The callback is always triggered for all keys, not just for updated ones.